# postfix не доставляет сообщения на другие эмейл

Tags: mysql, linux, email, postfix, dovecot

Установил Postfix + Dovecot + Postfixadmin, пытаюсь отправить через Postfixadmin сообщение на внешние эмэйлы, сообщения не доходят, но при этом в postfixadmin пишет, что сообщение успешно отправлено.
https://selectel.ru/blog/postfix-dovecot-ubuntu/ Делал по этому гайду.

Выводы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: В вашем скриншоте написано: `message not accepted`. Вы для своего домена сделали запись SPF? DKIM настроили?

Comment: Он не может найти адрес root@mail......ru поиском по мускулевой базе, о чём честно вам дважды пишет. Почему он его ищет и почему не может найти - это вопросы, которые предстоит решить вам. Вообще, при настройке почтового сервера я бы сначала прочитал документацию по этому серверу. Целиком. Раз пять. Чтобы хотя бы приблизительно понимать, как оно вообще работает и чего примерно хочет.